# final annotation and decorator in python3.8

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, python-3.8

As Python 3.8 releasing soon just wanted to know the difference between **The final decorator and The Final annotation**.

Comment: You can read all about it in [PEP 591 -- Adding a final qualifier to typing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/).

Comment: PEP 591 is pretty clear on what ``final`` is there for. So the answer is either an unhelpful "No, No, Yes" or a very exhaustive discussion what ``final`` is and what it should, can, will and won't do. Please clarify what exactly is your question that you need answered.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi just saw the PEP 591 and found little bit confuse about final annotation and decorator , have edited the question for more precise.

Answer (score 30):

In Python 3.8 the Python type hinting feature (embodied by the [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)) will support marking names as *final*. This is documented in [PEP 591 – *Adding a final qualifier to typing*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/).

What this means is that the `typing` module gains two new objects:

- The [`typing.Final` typing construct](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Final)
- The [`@typing.final()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.final).

To be up-front: *The Python language itself does not gain `final` syntax or support*. The above objects do not alter how Python works, they are constructs that *merely document* that an object or reference is to be considered final. The new objects can trivially be backported to older Python releases. The [`typing-extensions` project](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/), which provides backports of `typing` features from later to earlier Python versions, [has already included these objects](https://github.com/python/typing/commit/c6c7dfdd4b999a2bbd46d120adeacc504d74e044).

Their use lies in using a type hint *checker* like [mypy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.final) to check that your project correctly treats the objects so documented as final.

Their use is otherwise exactly like that of the [`final` keyword in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)): to state that a specific reference can only be assigned to *once*, that a method cannot be overridden in a subclass, or that a class definition cannot be subclassed.

- Use the `typing.Final` object to mark a global or attribute as final, documenting that the value will never change once assigned to:

  ```
    GLOBAL_CONSTANT: Final[str] = "This is a constant value because it is final"
  ```
- Use the `@typing.final` decorator to mark a method as non-overridable (subclasses can't define a different implementation) or a class as non-inheritable (you can't create subclasses from the class):

  ```
    @final
    class FinalClass:
        """This class can't be inherited from"""

    class SomeClass:
        @final
        def final_method(self):
            """Subclasses can't define a different final_method implementation"""
  ```

Also see the [mypy documentation on their use](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/final_attrs.html), which covers such details as to what ways of assigning the value of a `Final` attribute are acceptable.

Demo:

```
$ cat demo.py
from typing import final, Final

# FOO is marked final, can't assign another value to it
FOO: Final[int] = 42

class Foo:
    @final
    def spam(self) -> int:
        """A final method can't be overridden in a subclass"""
        return 42

@final
class Bar:
    """A final class can't be subclassed"""

# Rule breaking section
FOO = 81

class Spam(Foo, Bar):
    def spam(self) -> int:
        return 17

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("FOO:", FOO)
    print("Spam().spam():", Spam().spam())

$ python3.8 demo.py   # Python will not throw errors here
FOO: 81
Spam().spam(): 17
$ mypy demo.py        # only a type checker will
demo.py:17: error: Cannot assign to final name "FOO"
demo.py:19: error: Cannot inherit from final class "Bar"
demo.py:20: error: Cannot override final attribute "spam" (previously declared in base class "Foo")
```