# Does the final decorator help in preventing method overriding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to create a final method in my class, where I want that it cannot be overridden by any sub-class, just like when creating a final class using final decorator which cannot be inherited.

```
from final_class import final


class Dummy:
    def show(self):
        print("show id running from dummy")

    @final
    def display(self):
        print("display from dummy")

class Demo(Dummy):
    def show(self):
        print("show from demo")

    def display(self):
        print("display from demo")

d = Demo()
d.display()
```

I think we should get an error when accessing the display method from Demo, but when I run the program it gives "display from demo".

So what am I missing? I have checked [final annotation and decorators in python3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596086/final-annotation-and-decorator-in-python3-8) but it talks about typechecking in typing packages while I was trying it from the final_class package.

Comment: If you're using an IDE you will get a warning on `display` inside `Demo`, which is generally what `typing` is used for. It doesn't enforce Runtime errors...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [final annotation and decorator in python3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596086/final-annotation-and-decorator-in-python3-8) (specifically, "*The above objects do not alter how Python works, they are constructs that merely document that an object or reference is to be considered final*." and also see the demo example that shows an error _only when using a type checker_ like mypy)

Comment: Python does not have true private, or etc. However, IDEs support that, when you try to override `display` it will show an error message without an explicit denial.

Comment: According to [its sparse documentation](https://github.com/moscow-python-beer/final-class), the decorator from the `final_class` package only goes *on the class itself*, not individual methods…

Comment: People here were quick to close your question because your code focused on `typing.final`. (Now you edited it.) If your actual intent was to ask "how can I prevent method overriding", you should articulate it accordingly and focus on that. You can mention that you _tried_ using `@final`, but it did not work, but emphasize that you want to know how to prevent method overriding in general.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg My main reason to ask this question is to know the working of the final decorator but got confused as both typing and final_class package contains final decorator. One only does the type checking and one gives an error while inheriting a class which is declared using final decorator. And I thought that if inheriting class gives error, then overriding method should also give error.

Comment: As the name implies, `final_class` is for final *classes*. Not final methods.

Comment: All `final_class.final` does is set a class's `__init_subclass__` to a method that raises a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

As seem in the comments, the 3rd party library `final_class.final` is one thing: a class decorator that will prevent, at runtime, that a class is further inherited, anf `typing.final` which ships with Python, and is intended  to decorate both classes and methods, but which has no enforcing behavior during program execution - it will, instead, make any compliant static analysis tool to raise an error in the type-checking stage.

It is, due to Python flexibility and dynamism, possible to create a `final` decorator for methods that will be enforced at runtime: i.e. whenever a subclass is created overriding a method marked as final in the inheritance chain, a `RuntimeError`, or other custom error can be raised.

The idea is that whenever a new class is created, both methods on the metaclass and the `__init_subclass__` method of the bases is called - so, if one wants to create a custom metaclass or custom base-class to be used along with such a `@final` decorator, it should be something more or less straightforward.

What would be less straightforward would be such a decorator that would work regardless of an specific base class or custom-metaclass - and this also can be done: by injecting in the class being constructed an `__init_subclass__` method which will perform a check of violation of the `final` clause.

The complicated part is to co-exist with eventual pre-existing `__init_subclass__` methods which also need to be called, either on the same class or in any superclass, as well as emulate the working of `super()`, since we are creating a method outside the class body. The decorator code can inspect the context from which its called and inject a `__init_subclass__` there, taking some care:

```
import sys

def final(method):
    f = sys._getframe().f_back
    
    _init_subclass_meth = "super"
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        # all of these are readonly, so nonlocal is optional:
        # nonlocal final_methods, _init_subclass_meth, _original_init_subclass, __init_subclass__
        
        # In a normal __init_subclass__, one can know about the class in which
        # a method is declared, and call super(), via the `__class__`
        # magic variable. But that won't work for a method defined
        # outside the class and inkected in it. 
        # the line bellow should retrieve the equivalent to __class__
        current_class = next(supercls for supercls in cls.__mro__ if getattr(supercls.__dict__.get("__init_subclass__", None), "__func__", None) is __init_subclass__)
        
        for meth_name in cls.__dict__:
            if meth_name in final_methods:
                raise RuntimeError(f"Final method {meth_name} is redeclared in subclass {cls.__name__} from {current_class.__name__}")            
        
        if _init_subclass_meth == "wrap":
            return _original_init_subclass(cls, *args, **kwd)
        return super(current_class, None).__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
    
    __init_subclass__._final_mark = True
    if "__init_subclass__" in f.f_locals and not getattr(f.f_locals["__init_subclass__"], "_final_mark", False):
        _init_subclass_meth = "wrap"
        _original_init_subclass = f.f_locals["__init_subclass__"]
        
    # locals assignment: will work in this case because the caller context
    # is a class body, inside which `f_locals` refers usually to a 
    # plain dict (unless a custom metaclass changed it).
    # This normally would not work (= no effect) in an ordinary frame, 
    # represnting a plain function or method in execution:
    f.f_locals["__init_subclass__"] = __init_subclass__
    final_methods = f.f_locals.setdefault("_final_methods", set())
    final_methods.add(method.__name__)
    return method

class A:
    @final 
    def b(self):
        print("final b")
```

And this will raise an error:

```
class B(A):
    def b(self):
        # RuntimeError expected
        ...
```